# Premature end of script headers (laravel on plesk)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, plesk

I am redirecting to a view with an array (`redirect()->back()-with([ 'array' => $array])`), this works fine on my local environment (with any array size), but on my VPS (Plesk) environment this works only when the array is somewhat small.

Now I googled this for a day and tried many things, including adding nginx buffer size directives, and this made it so that my redirect sends a 500 error, or it redirects but doesn't send the array.

Comment: check the error logs

Comment: Please share your nginx configuration as well as the error_log showing the message of the request ending in HTTP 500.

Comment: What session driver are you using and is it the same locally?